# if/else grepl "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r

I want to perform a set of operations (in R) on a number of data frames located within a list. In particular, for each of one I create a "library" column, which is then used to determine which kind of filtering operation to perform. This is the actual code:

```
sampleList <- list(RNA1 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R4T2_S2.txt",
              RNA2 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R4T3_S4.txt",
              RNA3 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R5T2_S1.txt",
              RNA4 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R5T3_S2.txt",
              RNA5 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T5_S1.txt",
              RNA6 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T6_S1.txt",
              RNA7 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T6_S2.txt",
              RNA8 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T7_S2.txt",
              RNA9 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T8_S3.txt",
              RNA10 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T9_S3.txt",
              RNA11 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R14T9_S4.txt",
              DNA1 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna10_1_S4.txt",
              DNA2 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna10_2_S5.txt",
              DNA3 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna10_3_S6.txt",
              DNA4 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna50_1_S1.txt",
              DNA5 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna50_2_S2.txt",
              DNA6 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna50_3_S3.txt",
              DNA7 = "data/not_processed/dedup.dna50_pcrcocktail_S7.txt")

batch <- lapply(names(sampleList),function(mysample){
  aux <- read.table(sampleList[[mysample]], col.names=c(column1, column2, ..., ID, library, column4, etc...))
  aux %>% mutate(library = mysample, R = Fw_ref + Rv_ref, A = Fw_alt + Rv_alt) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all=T)
  if (grepl("DNA", aux$library)){
    aux %>% filter(aux$R>1 & aux$A>1)
  } else {
    aux %>% filter((aux$R+aux$A)>7 & aux$Fw_ref>=1 & aux$Rv_ref>=1 & aux$Fw_alt>=1 & aux$Rv_alt>=1)
  }
  aux
})

batch_file <- do.call(rbind, batch)
write.table(batch_file, "data/batch_file.txt", col.names = T, sep = "\t")
```

The possible values of the library column are DNA1 to DNA7, and RNA1 to 11. I tried also with "char" %in%, but it gives the same problem:

Error in if (grepl("DNA", aux$library)) { : argument is of length zero

Seems like the if condition is not able to identify the value in library. However, when I tried to apply the if/else condition on the batch_file (not filtered, basically obtained with this code without the if/else part) it worked perfectly.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ditto for the lines inside the `if`. You run a `filter` on `aux`, but leave `aux` unchanged. If you want to modify `aux`, you need `aux <- aux %>% ...`

Comment: I updated with the way I create my samplelist. I am trying to filter out rows using different criteria, depending on whether the rows belong to either DNA1/2../7 or RNA1/...11.

Comment: Gregor I tried also in this way, but the error is the same. Thank you anyway: I missed that part.

Comment: I got it, but the column looks like as it should be: all rows from RNA1 = "data/not_processed/dedup.Bp1R4T2_S2.txt" have RNA1 as value, and so on for all the others. Since the column is created just before the if/else, I thought this would be fine.

I just tried by switching to aux <- aux %>% mutate(library=...) and seemed to work, but the final file is much smaller than expected..